# Qt installation error

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qt-creator

i got an error when am trying to configure Qt.

```
Erro :
    execute: File or path is not found (nmake)
    execute: File or path is not found (nmake)
    Cleaning qmake failed, return code -1




// installion files.
    InterBase...............no

Sources are in..............E:\xampp\Qt\4.6
Build is done in............E:\xampp\Qt\4.6
Install prefix..............E:\xampp\Qt\4.6
Headers installed to........E:\xampp\Qt\4.6\include
Libraries installed to......E:\xampp\Qt\4.6\lib
Plugins installed to........E:\xampp\Qt\4.6\plugins
Binaries installed to.......E:\xampp\Qt\4.6\bin
Docs installed to...........E:\xampp\Qt\4.6\doc
Data installed to...........E:\xampp\Qt\4.6
Translations installed to...E:\xampp\Qt\4.6\translations
Examples installed to.......E:\xampp\Qt\4.6\examples
Demos installed to..........E:\xampp\Qt\4.6\demos

Creating qmake...
execute: File or path is not found (nmake)
execute: File or path is not found (nmake)
Cleaning qmake failed, return code -1


E:\xampp\Qt\4.6>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are trying to build Qt with a Visual Studio enviroment, you have to make sure that `nmake` and `cl` are in the `PATH`.

The easiest way to do that is to simply use the Visual Studio Command Prompt (found e.g. in the start menu).

Comment: no, i dont want to work with Visual Studio. I just want the Qt alone.

Comment: With what do you want to build Qt then? You need to build it somehow to get the binaries.

Comment: if you want Qt alone, I guess you want mingw32, that is included in the open source SDK releases for Windows. (Another compiler, not Microsoft's, but still a compiler...)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your path so that it leads to wherever nmake is.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the flag "-make nmake" to your configure command.

Comment: Maybe this only works in older versions of Qt; In Qt 5.7.0: "Unknown part nmake passed to -make."